# How to make a popup command work in python

Tags: python, popup

So I am trying to make a popup screen. My code looks as follow:

```
def Popup_scale():
    popup = Tk()
    popup.wm_title("!")
    label = Label(popup, text="Controleer of de weegschaal is aangesloten!", font=LETTER_20)
    label.pack(side='top', fill='x', padx=10)
    label = Label(popup, text="En druk daarna op Oké", font=LETTER_20)
    label.pack(side='top', fill='x', pady = 10, padx=10)
    B_ok = Button(popup, text='oké', command = popup.destroy, font=LETTER_20)
    B_ok.pack(pady=10)
    popup.mainloop()
```

Now this works fine, but I want my program to restart whenever I press the 'Oke' button. Therefore I use this command:

```
os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)
```

But when I do use that command instead of popup.destroy, the program executes the command at the exact moment it creates the button. I can't figure out why. Also when I change the code to the following code:

```
def Popup_scale():
    def Reboot():
        popup.destroy
    popup = Tk()
    popup.wm_title("!")
    label = Label(popup, text="Controleer of de weegschaal is aangesloten!", font=LETTER_20)
    label.pack(side='top', fill='x', padx=10)
    label = Label(popup, text="En druk daarna op Oké", font=LETTER_20)
    label.pack(side='top', fill='x', pady = 10, padx=10)
    B_ok = Button(popup, text='oké', command = Reboot(), font=LETTER_20)
    B_ok.pack(pady=10)
    popup.mainloop()
```

The destroy command won't work any longer. However, if I use this code but then with de reboot program line, I get the same problem of the program executing the command when it creates the button.

Am I doing something completely wrong?